# I am with problem to run test in project Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

My test function is this

```
use RefreshDatabase;

public function create_route()
{
    $user = \App\Models\User::factory()->create();

    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->post(route('daily-logs.store'), [
            'log' => 'Logging from create route test',
            'day' => '2020-01-01',
        ]);

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('daily_logs', [
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'log'     => 'Logging from create route test',
        'day'     => '2020-01-01 00:00:00',
    ]);
}
```

My route is this:

```
Route::post('/daily-logs', [DailyLogController::class, 'store'])->name('daily-logs.store');
```

My controller is this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return DailyLog::create([
        'user_id'=> $request->user()->id,
        'log'=> $request->log,
        'day'=> $request->day,
    ]);
}
```

if i access my router using the browser with request post, the job was done successfully. But, if I am using my test function, an error message is displayed.

[image]

Whats wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the validation passes? It's either that, or the `DailyLog`'s `$fillable` property needs to be updated.

Comment: Yes @cdruc, I am tested with and without of validade.

Comment: Hmm...that's weird. Are you using the `RefreshDatabase` trait?

Test if it even hits the controller action by placing a `dd($request->all());` before the create - then run the test.

Comment: @cdruc I tested it and did not answer.
it is as if he did not enter the route. but as shown earlier, the route exists. and it works by browser.

Comment: Yes, I use RefreshDatabase

Comment: check your error logs and run a dump on the output of the call: `$this->actingAs($user)->post(...)->dump()`

Comment: @tanerkay I got this:
https://puu.sh/HIoag/dd76252a83.png

Comment: @RafaelFurtado that explains it then. The action is never performed. Maybe you have some custom auth logic that is preventing `actingAs($user)` from working as expected. One way to test this might be to try `Auth::login($user)`

Comment: @tanerkay First of all, thank you very much for your help.
I am using Fortify and JetStream for authenticate

Comment: It depends on the individual case. Could it be a different auth guard? e.g. do you need to use `actingAs($user, 'fortify')`, replacing `fortify` with the relevant guard name if you are not using the default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the action was never performed.

It is a good practice in Laravel tests to create an assertion on HTTP calls.

e.g.

```php
    $this->post(...)
        ->assertSuccessful(); // or assertRedirect(), assertStatus(), ...
```

This will only tell you that the status code (e.g. 302 does not match a successful status code).

To debug, one way is to dump the response:

```php
    $this->post(...)
        ->dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your migration to look for `dateTime` rather than `date`.

```
Schema::create('daily_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
  $table->text('log');
  $table->dateTime('day'); // <<<< change date to datetime
  $table->timestamps();
});
```